# How to know that java method is blocking a current thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, api

How to know, that method which I'm using is blocking a thread or it is running it's own thread? Is there any sign in API?
Example from android- method which is scanning for BLE devices:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#startLeScan%28android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback%29
It is running (scanning) until I will stop it manually. How I can know if I should call this method in another thread, to do not block a user's interaction possibility?

Comment: this particular method returns true if a scan is started, i think it wont block  the thread, instead probably start a new thread in which the scan is preformed.

Answer (score 4):

A few ways-

Logcat will tell you if the UI is hanging due to too much work on the UI thread.

Also, there is Strict Mode which you can enable on develop builds https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html

Bottom line, if the UI remains responsive and Logcat is clean then you probably don't have any problems.